# How works install in my project by library IIPDFLib?

Tags: delphi

world. I tryed to install to my delphi 11 lib IIPDFLib, but actually, idk how to connect it with Delphi besides SEARCH_PATH in Delphi compiler options. Cuz when i put "IIPDFLib" in uses section - delphi cant find it. What i do wrong, guys?

Just cloned lib and set search path.

Comment: Did you actually compile the lib and have any `.dcu`/`.lib`/`.dll`/`.bpi`/`.bpl` file(s) for it? If not, have you tried simply adding the lib's `.pas` file(s) to your project?